# How to make my Web service available to Universe?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I am developing my web service in ASP.NET.Where can i register my web service for global access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add your service to a public registry where anybody can serach for it and use it, have a look at [www.xmethods.net](http://www.xmethods.net)

Answer (score 1):

you mean by Global access is internet?
if so just you need to have router with real IP, and then from the router configuration you set what's the IP of the server.
After that you site will be accessed from the internet.